# How to maintain your Windows as fast as the day you freshly installed it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, cpu

I just installed windows 10 and it's pretty fast, but I know the fact that performance will drop gradually.
is there any tips on how to maintain PC working smoothly for longest possible time?

Comment: One thing that makes the most difference for me is browsing. This is what I do most on my computer. I don't see that many performance issues with other apps. If you're into gaming or video-editing, it might be a different story. For me it's browsing. And browsing gets slower over time. Why? (1) Webpages require more power. All these javascript libraries that do something, all this CSS, it's getting more and more, not less. (2) I tend to install more and more addons over time. This slows things down. (3) I have more tabs open over time. Of course 2 and 3 can be influenced...

Comment: use a SSD and Windows will be always fast

Comment: @magicandre1981 what is SSD? sorry if it's too nooby

Comment: 5s google search brings you to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive. SSD = flash based drive which is MUCH faster compared to a HDD

Answer (score 0):

The performance drop would not occur if all you did is to use the OS and the apps you installed the first day. Even if you constantly generate data, i.e. documents, drawings, pictures, charts, schematics, recordings, music, animation, video, etc.

Performance degradation occurs as a result of the following activities:

- Change in the disk layout
- Installing, testing and uninstalling apps that leave crud behind

You can do the following to help your machine overcome these problems:

- Perform defragmentation regularly. Windows 10 does it for you, so all you have to do is not to interfere with its ability to do so.
- Test your apps in a sandbox or a virtual machine. Only make the installation permanent once you made sure you actually want the app.

## Testing software while keeping the operating system clean

If you want to install software to test them, consider doing so either within a sandbox or virtual machine.

A virtual machine is an emulation of a full computer inside your computer. You can use Hyper-V (comes with Windows 10), VirtualBox, VMware Workstation Player or VMware Workstation to create a virtual machine. Install an OS on the virtual machine and then create a snapshot of your virtual machine after you finished setting them up. You can now test your software in them. Once the test if finished, revert the changes by restoring to your snapshot.

A sandbox isolates changes to your computer allowing you to revert changes as if they didn't happen. A sandbox is not as effective as a virtual machine but it offers more performance. Comodo Internet Security and Acronis True Image come with sandboxing solutions. In case of Comodo Internet Security, you run the program inside the sandbox and once you finished testing it, you reset the sandbox. You can keep the app indefinitely in the sandbox. In case of True Image, you start the sandbox and then whatever you do happens within the sandbox. Then, you just reset the sandbox. This means Acronis's sandbox is meant to be temporary.

In addition to Comodo Internet Security and Acronis True Image, there are dedicated sandboxing apps like Sandboxie and Deep Freeze.